# Reports generated in Sales cloud upon clicking Related Individual Email Results [SENT, OPEN, ...] not available in Lightning? only on Classic?

Tags: marketing-cloud, lightning, marketing-cloud-connect, email-tracking

Does this is a limitation of Marketing Cloud Connector?
Where in upon clicking on any of the SENT, OPEN, BOUNCE on Related Individual Email Results under the **Email Sends** tab in Sales cloud.

Any one has a work around for lightning mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Lightning** Experience is not supported for **Marketing Cloud Connect** features. Those using Lightning Experience with Salesforce are automatically redirected to **Salesforce Classic** when any Marketing Cloud Connect tabs are clicked.

Source: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_connect_the_clouds.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null

Comment: @ zuzannamj thanks for confirming on this!.